# Which owner group does `ls -l` show?

Tags: permissions, group

When the file owner is part of several groups, how does `ls -l` decide which group to show? For example, on MacOS, I see

```
drwx------+  48 flow2k  staff             1536 Feb  5 10:11 Documents
drwxr-xr-x+ 958 flow2k  _lpoperator      30656 Feb 22 16:07 Downloads
```

Here groups shown for the two directories are different (`staff` and `_lpoperator`) - what is this based on? I am a member of both groups.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this question stems from a misunderstanding of how groups work. The groups listed in `ls -l` are not the group that the *user* is potentially in, but the group that the *file* is owned by. Each file is owned by a user and a group. Often, this user is in the group, but this is not necessary. For example, my user is in the following groups:

```
$ groups
audio uucp sparhawk plugdev
```

but not in, say, the group `cups`. Now, let's create a file.

```
$ touch foo
$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 sparhawk sparhawk 0 Feb 23 21:01 foo
```

This is owned by the user `sparhawk`, and the primary group for me, which is also called `sparhawk`. Let's now change the group owner of the file.

```
$ sudo chown sparhawk:cups foo
changed ownership of 'foo' from sparhawk:sparhawk to sparhawk:cups
$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 sparhawk cups 0 Feb 23 21:01 foo
```

You can see that the group that now owns the file is not a group that I am in.

This concept allows precise manipulation of file permissions. For example, you could create a group with members X, Y, and Z, and share files between the three of them. You could further give X write permissions, but only give the others (the group) read permissions.

Comment: There is rarely a need to use `sudo` to set permissions.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Was that the -1? Even if I *had* used `sudo` unnecessarily, that seems harsh. In any case, I tested the commands as I wrote the answer. Without `sudo`, I got `chown: changing ownership of 'foo': Operation not permitted`. If, however, I `chown` with a group I *am* a member of, then `sudo` is not required. Is it different on your system?

Comment: @Sorry I can't remember why the -1, maybe I pressed the wrong button. You are correct, that you can not change the owning group, to a group that you are not in. But why do you have to? (maybe sgid for executable) You can use ACLs.

Comment: There was indeed a misunderstanding on my part; thanks for clarifying that up. So, for my case, it would seem some other process, perhaps the OS, had somehow assigned different group owners for `Documents` and `Downloads`. Is this your interpretation as well?

Comment: @flow2k Probably? It could also be a change in the primary group, but either way, I would ask a new question about this.

Comment: are you sure we need group and owner though? wouldn't just group suffice? https://talk.ahoxus.org/notice/AIrpBTXa6UvXvueehM

Answer (score 2):

In traditional permissions a file will belong to one group, no matter how many groups a user belongs to.

When a file is created
The group is set to the primary group of the user.
The user can then move it to any of their groups.

## If you have ACLs (Posix ACLs, may differ from ACLs on MacOS)

then there can be more than one group. However ls only shows the first group, and the mode shows the group mask. (This can be confusing. It would be better if it showed ACL for the group name).

A user can not change the first group to any group that they are not a member of. But they can add auxiliary group and user permissions (for any group or user).

You do not need root (sudo) permissions to do any of this.

Comment: Note that this is granting permissions to groups, _not_ changing the "group owner" of the file.  It's a subtle difference.  Granting permissions doesn't need `sudo`, but changing ownership _may_.

Comment: What more can an owning group do?

Comment: As you hinted in another comment, setgid gives the process the effective group permission of the group owner.

Comment: @StephenHarris Doesn't `chown` always require `sudo`?

Comment: Well, `chown` without changing the owner (essentially `chgrp`) does not require sudo.

Comment: @flow2k `chgrp` can change the group of **a file that you own**, to any **group that you are a member of**.  And yes changing owner will need privileges (however there are ways around it, if you have write access to the directory).

Comment: Yes, with write access to (parent) dir, I could 1. copy the file to somewhere else, 2. delete the file, and 3. recreate the file with myself as owner. (This works if I'm the parent dir owner; otherwise, this works only if the sticky bit is not set on the parent dir).